# load large data and split and store into two tables in sql server

Tags: sql-server, migration, python

I need to take **large amount of data** from a table and split that into two different tables in databse (sql server). How it is  possible. i need to automate this action either in sql server side or python(flask) side (any method is fine) which one will be better and faster ?. Can anyone help me how to do this data migration?
this is the **sample** structure of my table and sample data
**This is my source table  [Order_table]**

| order_id | order_amount | custome_id | customer_name | item_id | item_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3000 | 200 | Arun | 10 | shirt |
| 1 | 3000 | 200 | Arun | 100 | pant |
| 2 | 500 | 201 | Sam | 2 | tshirt |
| 3 | 1500 | 202 | David | 6 | shirt |

**And these are my destination tables:**

(1) =>[new_Order_table]

| order_id | order_amount | custome_id | customer_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3000 | 200 | Arun |
| 2 | 500 | 201 | Sam |
| 3 | 5500 | 202 | David |

(2) => [customer_details_table]

| order_id | item_id | item_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | shirt |
| 1 | 100 | pant |
| 2 | 2 | shirt |
| 4 | 6 | tshirt |

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: TaKe a look at [mcve] for details on constructing your question.  Include any queries or code you may have tried, and indicate if you've had problems with something not working.

Comment: This sounds like a relatively straightforward [ETL (or ELT) need](https://www.sqlshack.com/an-overview-of-etl-and-elt-architecture/). You might try doing some research using "ETL" as your search keyword, then honing your question here to be more targeted to the problems you're having. That will likely make the question be better received, and more likely to get a helpful answer.

Comment: Is this a one time change or you'll need to routinely and continuously split the single table's data into the two separate tables?